# Is there a way to make rollapply always pass a matrix to my function?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

Is there a way to make rollapply always pass a matrix to my function? Or a good way to deal with it when it doesn't pass the matrix to my function?

Suppose I have the following:

```
library(zoo)
v <- read.zoo(data.frame(dt=as.Date('2011-01-01')+0:9, a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30), index.column = "dt")
v
            a  b  c
2011-01-01  1 11 21
2011-01-02  2 12 22
2011-01-03  3 13 23
2011-01-04  4 14 24
2011-01-05  5 15 25
2011-01-06  6 16 26
2011-01-07  7 17 27
2011-01-08  8 18 28
2011-01-09  9 19 29
2011-01-10 10 20 30
```

Suppose I want to run a rollapply:

```
rollapplyr(v, seq_along(index(v)), by.column = F, FUN = function(x) { sum(x['a'] * x['b']) })
```

I get the following result:

```
2011-01-01 2011-01-02 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05 2011-01-06 2011-01-07 2011-01-08 2011-01-09 2011-01-10 
        11         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Why are there NAs? I think what is happening is that the first iteration uses a vector and the rest of the iterations use a matrix. Is there a way to make it always roll over a matrix? or what is the best way to deal with the different types that are returned by rollapply?

I would like to get a cumulative product like:

```
            cumprod 
2011-01-01  1 * 11 = 11  (vector in function)
2011-01-02  1 * 11 + 2 * 12 = 35 (matrix in function)
2011-01-03  1 * 11 + 2 * 12 + 3 * 13 = 74 (matrix in function)
...
```

I always end up attacking these types of problems using a construct like the following but just wondering if this is correct as converting the vector to a matrix sounds hackey (just wondering if there is a better way to deal with this problem):

```
  rollapplyr(v, seq_along(index(v)), by.column = F, FUN = function(x) {
    if (is.vector(x))
      x = matrix(x, nrow=1, ncol=length(x), dimnames = list(NULL, names(x)))

    sum(x[,'a'] * x[,'b'])
  })
```

> NOTE: I am not interested in cumprod - this is just an example
>   problem.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these will provide the cumulative sum shown in the question.  Note that in the last one that `by.column=FALSE` causes all columns to be passed at once and `coredata=FALSE` causes it to be passed as a zoo object.

```
cumsum(v$a * v$b)

rollapplyr(v$a * v$b, 1:nrow(v), sum)

rollapplyr(v, 1:nrow(v), function(x) sum(x$a * x$b), 
  by.column = FALSE, coredata = FALSE)
```